# MongoServerError: bad auth : Authentication failed for dotenv

Tags: mongodb, express

when I use `dotenv` for hiding my password and username this error happens, but if I don't use `dotenv` the error disappears:

```sh
MongoServerError: bad auth : Authentication failed.
    at Connection.onMessage (E:\my work\web development by zhankar\assignment\assignment-11-warehouse\warehouse-backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:203:30)
    at MessageStream.<anonymous> (E:\my work\web development by zhankar\assignment\assignment-11-warehouse\warehouse-backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:63:60)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at processIncomingData (E:\my work\web development by zhankar\assignment\assignment-11-warehouse\warehouse-backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:108:16)
    at MessageStream._write (E:\my work\web development by zhankar\assignment\assignment-11-warehouse\warehouse-backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:28:9)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:754:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:28) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 8000,
  codeName: 'AtlasError',
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are likely using dotenv in the wrong way.

- Show how are you passing the variables

Basically, this is a minimal example:

```
#.env file
username=john
password=alice
```

No spaces around the `=`

```
//server.js
require('dotenv')()
//that populates process.env
console.log(process.env.password, process.env.username)
```

So to be clear, your details are stored in the process.env object.